# How to find the order of a Stack during testing in Flutter?

Tags: testing, flutter, stack

Say I have a Stack of widgets that are not the same:

```
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(),
    Text('Hey'),
    Positioned(top: 300.0, child: CustomWidget()),
  ],
);
```

How do I test the order of the child widgets? I could assign keys to each item, but how can I tell which item appears in front of another?

I could assign a key to my Stack, wrap each child in a `Positioned`, and then use `find.byKey(stackKey)` to get my Stack, and then use `find.byType(Positioned)` to get its children. This returns an `Iterable` which I can convert to a `List`. But, is `find.byType()` guaranteed to return the same order each time?

Comment: the last one has the highest z-index.  Text is on top of Container, Positioned on top of Text.

Comment: How do I find the z-index during a test though?

Comment: z-index is just a web/css term, indicating its height on the z plane.   its not applicable to flutter (that i know of).

Comment: Right, in Flutter the property is `elevation`. The question is, how do we know the order of relative elevations, when we retrieve a list of Widgets in a Stack, during testing?

Answer (score 1):

What I did here was add Keys to the children on the Stack with the number of the expected order.

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      key: Key('StackChildKey1'),
    ),
    Container(
      key: Key('StackChildKey2'),
    ),
    Container(
      key: Key('StackChildKey3'),
    ),
  ],
),
```

On the test script, add all matching Keys to a List that we can check later.

```dart
List<String> widgetOrderList = [];
tester.allWidgets.forEach((Widget element) {
  /// Only add the Widget Key with the expected tag 'StackChildKey'
  if (element.key.toString().contains('StackChildKey')) {
    widgetOrderList.add(element.key.toString());
  }
});
```

Use `String.compareTo(String)` to validate the Widgets' order.

```dart
// This List<int> contains String.compareTo(String) results
/// https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/compareTo.html
/// 0 − when the Strings are equal.
/// 1 − when the first String is greater than the second
/// -1 − when the first String is smaller than the second
List<int> sortCheck= [];
for (int i = 0; i < widgetOrderList.length; i++) {
  /// Compare current Widget Key with next while still within bounds
  if (i + 1 < widgetOrderList.length) {
    sortCheck.add(widgetOrderList[i].compareTo(widgetOrderList[i+1]));
  }
}
```

Then use `expect` to add the test case. This expects the result of `isWidgetStackSorted` to be true.

```
/// Flutter test expects that the [isWidgetStackSorted] to be true
/// if List<int> sortCheck contains either 0 or 1, this indicates
/// that a pair isn't in the correct order on Stack
var isWidgetStackSorted = !(sortCheck.contains(0) || sortCheck.contains(1));
expect(isWidgetStackSorted, true);
```

Complete Test.

```dart
void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  testWidgets('Test Stack Order', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build the app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

    List<String> widgetOrderList = [];
    tester.allWidgets.forEach((Widget element) {
      /// Only add the Widget Key with the expected tag 'StackChildKey'
      if (element.key.toString().contains('StackChildKey')) {
        widgetOrderList.add(element.key.toString());
      }
    });

    /// This List<int> contains String.compareTo(String) results
    /// https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/compareTo.html
    /// 0 − when the Strings are equal.
    /// 1 − when the first String is greater than the second
    /// -1 − when the first String is smaller than the second
    List<int> sortCheck= [];
    for (int i = 0; i < widgetOrderList.length; i++) {
      /// Compare current Widget Key with next while still within bounds
      if (i + 1 < widgetOrderList.length) {
        sortCheck.add(widgetOrderList[i].compareTo(widgetOrderList[i+1]));
      }
    }

    /// Flutter test expects that the [isWidgetStackSorted] to be true
    /// if List<int> sortCheck contains either 0 or 1, this indicates
    /// that a pair isn't in the correct order on Stack
    var isWidgetStackSorted = !(sortCheck.contains(0) || sortCheck.contains(1));
    expect(isWidgetStackSorted, true);
  });
}
```